# How do I split a list in python?

Tags: python-2.7, split

I'm rather new to python, but I have a problem. I have a text file that looks like a lists. For example:

1) Bla bla bla

2) Lol o lolol

3) ha hah ahah

How do I split each lines while removing the numbers and the parentheses at the same time.

Comment: A google search reveals some useful functions: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split . Did you do any research before asking this question?

Comment: [file.readlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and [string.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) or [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) should help you out

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is like that:

```
string = "1) Bla bla bla \n 2) Lol o lolol \n 3) ha hah ahah"
```

And if you print that it would be:

```
>>print string
 1) Bla bla bla 
 2) Lol o lolol 
 3) ha hah ahah
```

Know you can remove integer and parenthesis with this code:

```
b = "1234567890)("
for char in b:
    string = string.replace(char,"")
```

And after that split it by this code :

```
>>print string.split('\n')
[' Bla bla bla ', ' Lol o lolol ', ' ha hah ahah']
```

If you find a problem with convert your file, mention me in a comment.